# How do I write files to my local drive when using Google Colab?

Tags: excel, google-colaboratory

I have a set of data I want to write to an Excel file.  I'm using Google Colab, and while I successfully use the following snippet to import files into my notebook...

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

...I can't seem to figure out how to write files to my local drive.  I'm using the xlwt library to write the data to an Excel file, as follows:

```
wb.save('Washington_1791.xls')
```

It completes the task without throwing an error, but I'm not sure of the save location, and I need to get it to save to my local drive.  Google gives me lots of suggestions on how to import from the local drive, but not how to save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any files written by your Python code will be on the disk of the virtual machine on which the code is running: if you want to get the files to your local disk, you will have to download them explicitly.

To do this, go to the *Files* tab in the left pane (click the `(>)` in the upper left to open the pane). Within that file viewer you can right-click any file and choose "Download".

[image]